# No value found JSON Exception

Tags: android, json

I'm unable to figure out this `JSON` exception, the response is  retrieved from server via **volley**, i have a similar `JSON` response which parses exactly this way, i dont seem to figure out why this throwing No Value exception for product_id. please help, thanks in advance

**JSON Response**:

```
{
status: "success",
data: [
{
product_id: "18",
cat_id: "3",
sub_id: "0",
username: "trial",
product_name: "Android Oreo",
description: "dummy text.",
amount: "2000.00",
btc_price: "0.000937",
image_url: "69273315-material-wallpapers16.png",
negotiable: "no"
},
{
product_id: "19",
cat_id: "3",
sub_id: "2",
username: "aa",
product_name: "Google Pixel XL",
description: "dummy text",
amount: "280000.00",
btc_price: "0.131220",
image_url: "img7.jpg",
negotiable: "no"
}
]
}
```

**parse code**:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.get("status").toString().equals("success")) {
            JSONArray jsonarr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            String columns[] = {"product_id", "cat_id", "sub_id", "username", "product_name",
                    "description", "amount", "btc_price", "image_url", "negotiable"};
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String column : columns) {
                    temp.add(jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString(column));
                }
                arr.add(temp);

                shopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                shopAdapter.setLoading();
            }
        } else if (jsonObject.get("status").toString().equals("end")) {
            total = "end";
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: I have tested your code (more or less) and works perfectly... Can you give more details? (more code, the error...)

Comment: put your logcat here

Comment: oh...yea..i tested it in netbeans as well, i was able to access the product id..but android says No value found, what i only notice is that e.printStackTrace is not generating error according to the snippet above, just the second line e.getMessage() that tells me the error

Comment: my bad, i finally found the error, i had to change the server url to the right one..(copy-paste error)